# Google script to extract the first word in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script

[google-apps-script] Google script to extract the first word in a cell.
I would like write a google script to extract the first word in a cell in a google spreadsheet.

For example if the cell contains, 'John White'. I would like to extract the word, 'John'.

Comment: Isnt there a builtin split function? If so just split and take first element

Comment: Have you tried anything? Care to post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Sure can! If you know what cell you want to reference and what you want to split them by you can easily create a function to find the first word in a cell.

```
function getCellWord(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:A1');
  var wordArray = range.getValue().split(" "); //Split by space

  Logger.log(wordArray[0]); // first word
  Logger.log(wordArray[1]); // second word
  Logger.log(wordArray[2]); // third word

}
```