# Getting the word(s) out of a string that contain a specific character. (Like # or @ for example a post planner)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

currently I am making an open-source post planner for social media marketing. But unfortunately, I am running in some trouble.

I would like to get the mentions (words that contain @ as the first character)
& tags (words that contain # as the first character)

returned with ", " as a separator. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to build or find the function myself.

```
function getCellWord(input){ //Makes a array of all words
  var range = ss.getRange(input); //test
  var wordArray = range.getValue().split(" "); //Split by space

  return wordArray;
}
//Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073607/google-script-to-extract-the-first-word-in-a-cell

function getMentions(content){

  var wordArray = getCellWord(content);
  var wordCount = COUNTA(SPLIT(wordArray, " "))

  for(i=0;i>=wordCount;i++){ //don't know what logger is
    if(Logger.log(wordArray[i]).indexOf("@")>-1) {
    return Logger.log(wordArray[i]) + ", ";
    }
  }
}

Ra
```

nge not found in getCellWord()

Comment: What is `ss` in `getCellWord()` function?

Comment: The referenced post has more code to create `ss` and other stuff. Please follow that and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.pototype.filter` with regex matches when word starts with `# or @`

```js
let str = '@bluh something #meh';
let out = str.split(' ').filter(word => word.match(/^(?:@|#)/)).join();
console.log(out)
```

```js
let str = '@bluh something #meh';
let out = str.split(' ').filter(function(word) {
 return word.match(/^(?:@|#)/)
}).join();
console.log(out)
```

Comment: @RikvandenReijen where's the error? that's the function you pasted in comment.

Comment: Hey sorry I was blocked by the 5 min edit thing.

Hey AZ_ thanks for the quick response. Your script seems to be working in stack overflow but unfortunately when I try it like this in google app script I get the following error:

function getMentions(content){
  var out = content.split(" ").filter(word => word.match(/^(?:@|#)/)).join();
  return out
}

Syntaxis error: var out...

I used var instead of let because of missing ; error that I got before.

Comment: still, I don't see where is the syntax error paste the only message after Syntax Error.

Comment: @RikvandenReijen try the second snippet I have removed the arrow function.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I got it working! Have a great day my dude!

Comment: glad it helped.