# Part of File Name to show in a Google Sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a file name similar to the following: "First Last SS Form." I want to extract the "First" and automatically put that in a certain cell, and then "Last" in another cell. I am able to pull in the whole file name, but I just want those first two words.

Comment: Related question: [Google script to extract the first word in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089517/1330560). Don't worry that the question says "first word"; the answer shows how to reference _every_ word in the file name.

Comment: I am trying to take the file name and put only part of it in a cell. The link above looks like it is taking text from a cell and then extracting a word to another cell.

Comment: "The link above looks like it is taking text from a cell". True, but the text is assigned to a variable and the script lets the user select the 1st, 2nd, 3rd &/or 4th word. Isn't this the same as your scenario? When you say `I have a file name` - don't you mean either "I enter a file name in a cell" or a script gets the name of a file? If not, then where does the file name come from? Anyway, would you please describe your scenario and your goals in detail so we have a common understanding. BTW: `put that in a certain cell`; this could be dynamic with an internal function or via a script.

Comment: I am still learning, so I apologize for being unclear. The worksheet file I am working in is named "First Last SS Form." I want to put "First" into cell A8, and I want to put "Last" into cell B8. I am able to pull the whole file name "First Last SS Form" into A8 using a script, but I want to just pull one word into those two cells as mentioned. Would I use a splice command?

Comment: In this particular case, neither `SPLICE` nor `SLICE` add much benefit because they use an array to do their work. OTOH, once you have used `SPLIT` to break the file name into an array, its elements can easily be accessed as array values. BUT... I added a second script showing how `SLICE` would work. FWIW, `SLICE` leaves the array intact, and just returns a portion; whereas `SPLICE` changes the content of the array by removing/replacing an element. This could be very important if you weren't aware.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the information. I have read a bit about each, but your explanation was much easier to follow, and I appreciate the examples below. I will try them out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can extract given words in a string and put those values into given cells. This script is just one method.

---

**SCRIPT - Split**

```
/*
/ this script assumes that the name of the spreadsheet consists of at least two words separated by a space.
/ the script extracts the first word and saves it to Cell A8
/ the script extracts the second word and saves it to Cell B8
*/

function firstlastSplit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var ssName = ss.getName()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the spreadsheet name is: "+ssName)
  var wordArray = ssName.split(" "); //Split by space
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: FYI, the number of words in the file name = "+wordArray.length)
  
  // just for fun
  /*
  Logger.log(wordArray[0]); // first word
  Logger.log(wordArray[1]); // second word
  Logger.log(wordArray[2]); // third word
  Logger.log(wordArray[3]); // third word
  */

  // Word#1 > Cell A8
  sheet.getRange("A8").setValue(wordArray[0])
  // Word#2 > Cell B8
  sheet.getRange("B8").setValue(wordArray[1])

}
```

---

**SCRIPT - Split & Slice**

```
function firstlastSlice() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var ssName = ss.getName()
  Logger.log("the spreadsheet name is: "+ssName)
  var wordArray = ssName.split(" "); //Split by space 
  // just for fun
  /*
  / Logger.log(wordArray.slice(0, 1)) // DEBUG
  / Logger.log(wordArray.slice(1, 2)) // DEBUG
  */

  Word#1 > Cell A8
  sheet.getRange("A8").setValue(wordArray.slice(0, 1))
  // Word#2 > Cell B8
  sheet.getRange("B8").setValue(wordArray.slice(1, 2))

}
```